# Using let does not save the record

Tags: testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Give the below simple example :

```
let(:item) { create(:item }
it 'query by scope' do
  expect(Item.all.length).to eq 1
end
```

The test does not pass.

Adding `item.save` within the it block, the test pass. Using a `before(:each) { create(:item) }` instead of `let` make the test pass too.

Sounds obvious, as the point I might be missing, why is `let` not effectively creating the record in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `let!` instead. `let` is lazily evaluated, `let!` body is called immediately.

All the examples you provided are valid because of `let` being lazily evaluated. You could also just call `item` inside it (without `save`) and it should pass as well.